# XSLT 2.0: How to iterate over stored values of an array inside a for-each loop with conditional check?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am writing xsl stylesheet to extract information from iTunes Music Library. xml file.

I want to store track information of playlists in an array and later iterate over them to get more information. I am confused how to store values in an array in xslt?

My attempt is here:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" /> 
    <xsl:template match="/"> 

    <xsl:variable name="tracks"
           select="plist/dict/array/dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Playlist ID']=6711]/array/dict/integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']" />

    <!-- I want to iterate over that array outside for-each loop and gather more information, The below code is not working.-->

   <xsl:for-each select="$tracks">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
  <xsl:value-of select="plist/dict/dict/dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']="."]/integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']" />
  <xsl:value-of select="plist/dict/dict/dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']="."]/string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Name']" />
  <xsl:value-of select="plist/dict/dict/dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']="."]/string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Total Time']" />
  <xsl:value-of select="plist/dict/dict/dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']="."]/string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Location']" />
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>


    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

A typical Track Ids which are populated in array variable "tracks",  are represented in below manner in itunes list. I want to list Name, Location, time infor for each Track Ids stored in the array. Something wrong with my conditions.

```
<plist>
  <dict>
    <dict>
      <dict>
        <key>Track ID</key>
        <integer>1633</integer>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Right here</string>
        <key>Kind</key>
        <string>MPEG audio file</string>
        <key>Total Time</key>
        <integer>358870</integer>
        <key>Location</key>
        <string>/Users/rakesh/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/track1633.mp3</string>
      </dict>
      <dict> 
        <!-- Next Track info -->
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Here I am stuck. Can any XSLT experts here to help me out?

Comment: I've edited your answer to change some of your <dicts> to </dicts> so that the xml looks correct

Comment: Before submitting a question it would be wise to express it in unambiguous, non-confusing way. This is a badly formulated question: 1) there is no `key` element in the provided XML document with string value `'Playlist ID'`. 2) There is no wanted result provided. Even if the wanted result is the contents of a variable, it should be specified (as an XML fragment) -- not left unspecified. Based on this I am quite tempted to *downvote* this question and am not doing this immediately with the hope that you'd make the necessary improvements. No wonder you got only a single, convoluted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just create a variable and populate its results with an XPath expression all in one go rather than interate through to build it.

```
<xsl:variable name="tracks"
  select="plist/dict/array/dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Playlist ID']=6711]/array/dict/integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']" />
```

Alternatively you could use xsl:keys at the begining of your document, I'm assuming that the path to the track information is `/plist/dict/array/dict` with the first dict key being `Tracks`

```
<xsl:key 
        name="playlists"
        match="plist/dict/array/dict/array/dict/integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']"
        use="../../../integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Playlist ID']"
/>
<xsl:key 
       name="tracks" 
       match="/plist/dict/array[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Tracks']/dict"
       use="integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']"
/>
```

This allows you to do `key('playlists','4555')` to return all the trackids associated with playlist id `4555` and also `key('tracks','1234')` to get the dict object associated with track id `1234`

You can then combine the two together to do

```
<xsl:variable "mytracks" select="key('tracks',key('playlists','6711'))" />
```

That will set `$mytracks` equal to the array of dict objects for the tracks in playlist 6711.  It aslo has the benefits of the speed enhancement granted by xsl:key

EDIT UPDATE----

I'm guessing you are trying to make a CSV from this so this code should do that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:key
    name="playlists"
    match="plist/dict/array/dict/array/dict/integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']"
    use="../../../integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Playlist ID']"
  />
  <xsl:key
    name="tracks"
    match="/plist/dict/dict/dict"
    use="integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']"
  />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="myplaylist" select="'6711'"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('tracks',key('playlists',$myplaylist))">
      <xsl:value-of select="integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Name']"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Total Time']"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Location']"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to match a different playlist id just change the value of myplaylist

--EDIT Version without `xsl:key` ,again just alter the value of the *myplaylist* variable

--EDIT Now mofified to original sort order of playlist
--EDIT Attempt to work around Qt Limitations

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="myplaylist" select="'4053'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="playlist_tracks" select="/plist/dict/array/dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Playlist ID']=$myplaylist]/array/dict/integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']" />

    <xsl:for-each select="$playlist_tracks">
      <xsl:variable select="." name="current" />
      <xsl:for-each select ="/plist/dict/dict/dict[integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']=$current]" >
        <xsl:value-of select="integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Track ID']"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Name']"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="integer[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Total Time']"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="string[preceding-sibling::key[1]='Location']"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Doh I made a typo, I've now corrected it to search for the playlist.

Comment: Could you update the question to include info as to the xml path to the track information

Comment: I've updated my answer again taking a guess about how to access the track info

Comment: Updated to hopefully better answer your question

Comment: Thanks Bob, You are awesome, hats off!! Its working perfectly fine.

Comment: Even though all information are coming but the order issue still persists. So in a playlists if tracks are in order (7 3 1 2), I want information in that order. Currently as we are extracting information for plist/dict/dict/dict .. the order comes as (1 2 3 7). Assume numbers are track ids.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your solution is not working. Only 1st element of the playlist is getting printed. Any clue.

Comment: No, because when I cut and paste this style sheet I get multiple results :(

Comment: The pasted code works perfectly for me when I try, I've done a minor rewrite that removes one element of nesting - see if that works around qt's limitation